# why has different output in printf, the same output between a and a+1?

Tags: c

When I code in C programming, I write:

```
a = 2;
printf("%d %d", ++a, a);
```

and

```
a = 2;
printf("%d %d", ++a, a + 1);
```

as similar output

```
3 3
```

But When I swap them, they have diffrent:

```
a = 2;
printf("%d %d", a, ++a);
3 3
```

and

```
a = 2;
printf("%d %d", a+1, ++a);
4 3
```

why has different output?

Comment: Because it's not specified how `printf()` handles the arguments! It's unspecified behavior!

Comment: why a + 1 and a have the same output???

Comment: Because it's not specified what printf handles first! So it could be that the second argument is first and 2+1 is output 3 (without an assignment to a) and then argument one is handled and 2 increment is also 3!

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%d %d", a, ++a);
```

This leads to undefined behavior.
It depends on how `printf()` processes the arguements.